# Javascript and MongoDB - write to file

Tags: javascript, mongodb, benchmarking, writetofile

I'm using mongoDB on an ubuntu server. However I'm using a javascript to store data and do some map/reduce. I would like to measure these operations and write the results into a file. Somehow I fail to open a file and write into it.. I tried the following:

```
f = new File("myfile.txt");
if(f.open("w") == true)
{   
    f.write("test");
 f.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file` object within spidermonkey (the JS engine MongoDB uses, and coincidently the console) has been made obsolete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/File_object . Not only that but it wasn't standard to spidermonkey anyway so that was a long shot.

As @gkamal states, the best way is to pipe the output of the MongoDB console like so:

```
mongo someprocess.js > outpout
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the answers - I have never piped an output before, how would I do that? Have I to define the file (txt-file?)

Comment: That syntax above is quite accurate, you can replace `output` with `somefile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you can not write files using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to write to the console using println and redirect the output to file, pass the javascript file as a parameter to mongo.

```
mongo someprocess.js > outpout
```